# docker-composeで実行したときdocker.sockから情報を取得できない

Tags: go, docker

`github.com/moby/moby/client`のEventsメソッドを使ったDockerのイベントを取得するソフトウェアを作成しています。
以下のdockerコマンドを実行した場合はDockerのイベントを取得できますが、docker-composeで指定した場合に`Error response from daemon: {"message":"page not found"}`というエラーがでて失敗します。

```
docker run  -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e API_VERSION=1.37 docker-app /app/binary
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: /app/binary
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    env_file:
      - docker.env
```

なぜdocker-composeで実行したときだけエラーがでるのでしょうか。またどのように修正すればdocker-composeでもdockerコマンドを実行したときと同じ状況を再現できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker.env`内の`API_VERSION="1.37"`を`API_VERSION=1.37`に変えると動きました。
`env_file`を使うときは`"`を使えないようです。